# Android Why EditText ellipsize doesn't work?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have added an EditText to my layout, but the ellipsize doesn't work. Can anybody help me? Thanks.

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: set the property android:lines="1"

Comment: I don't understand your purpose here what do you mean by you want Edittext to ellip at end. If you keep typing in editText after the width the text will keep on scrolling to left.

Comment: PM's demand: when EditText lost focus, it should be presented on a single-line display and ellip at the end, but android:lines=1 and android:ellipsize=end won’t be working

Answer (score 4):

`Ellipsize="end"` wont work for editable `EditText` so you need to make the `EditText` as non editable to make it work. Use the following code

```
<EditText
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_margin="10dp"
       android:textSize="24dp"
       android:text="A long texttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt"
       android:lines="1"
       android:scrollHorizontally="true"
       android:ellipsize="end"
       android:singleLine="true"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       tools:ignore="Deprecated" />
```

Comment: Sorry, but i tried and i am unable to type in this EditText.

Comment: @AkshayKatariya to be able to type you should turn back `editbale="true"`

Comment: removed it as I was just trying to demonstrate the implementation 

Answer (score 0):

ellipsize maybe works only with

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:singleLine="true"
```

and sometimes we add one more

```
android:maxLines="n"
```